# Show class only on subpages of a parent link?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

So what i would like to achieve is to show a class only on subpages of a certain parent page and hide on the rest of the pages. I looked it up and learned i can achieve this with jQuery through page IDs. But this subpages keep getting updated so is there a way to make this automatic?

```
.sidebar {
```

example page and subpage;

```
https://example/event/   
https://example/event/pikachu
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the pathname: `const { pathname } = window.location`
2. Check if it's the pathname you want to target
3. Show the class

e.g.:

```
https://www.example.com/path1  <-- Hide the class
https://www.example.com/path1/path2  <-- Show the class
https://www.example.com/path1/path3  <-- Show the class
https://www.example.com/path1/path2/path4  <-- Show the class
etc...
```

```
// .sidebar class allowed only for sub paths of /path1
// This is the logic //////////////////////////
const { pathname } = window.location;
const target = /^\/path1.*/gim;
if (target.test(pathname) && pathname !== '/path1')
node.classList.add('sidebar');
else node.classList.remove('sidebar');
///////////////////////////////////////////////
```

You can test a demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uv7tm7?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion but i updated my question. I dont know why but i explained it wrong..